I want to use express route in typescript inversify and express
I want to use custom express route in inversify with express+typescript
So code is below:
App.ts
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { InversifyExpressServer } from 'inversify-express-utils';
import { appConfig } from "./config"
import { container } from './container';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import  Router from "./router"


let server = new InversifyExpressServer(container,Router,null,null,null,false);

server.setConfig((app) => {
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
      extended: true
    }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
  });

let serverInstance = server.build();
serverInstance.listen(3000);

Container.ts
import { Container } from 'inversify';
import { IProductService, ProductService } from './infrastructures/services/product.service';
import TYPES from './types';
import { ProductController, IProductController } from './controllers/product.controller';

let container = new Container();
container.bind<IProductService>(TYPES.ProductService).to(ProductService);
container.bind<IProductController>(TYPES.ProductController).to(ProductController);
export { container };

ProductController.ts
import { IProduct, ProductService } from "../infrastructures/services/product.service";
import TYPES from "../types";
import { inject, injectable } from "inversify";

export interface IProductController{
    get(): IProduct[]
}

@injectable()
export  class ProductController  implements IProductController{

    constructor(@inject(TYPES.ProductService) private productService: ProductService ) {}
    get(): IProduct[]{
        
        return this.productService.getProduct()
    }
    
}

Router.ts
import express  from "express"; 
import { ProductController } from "./product.controller";
import { ProductService } from "../infrastructures/services/product.service"
    

const Router = express.Router();  
let productCont = new ProductController(new ProductService);  
Router.get('/',productCont.get);
export default Router

I router.ts I have created object like:
let productCont = new ProductController(new ProductService);  
Router.get('/',productCont.get);

So I don't want to create object, inversify should handle like ProductController.ts
Please help on this

When using inversify you should never instantiate a class, you can do this
let productCont = container.get<ProductController>(TYPES.ProductController)
Router.get('/',productCont.get);

In the above you get the ProductController but what happens for the ProductService
In the container, you can define a scope for your classes.
I see that you have not set any scope for your classes so they are all in TransiantScope by default, so every time ProductController is invoked a new instance will be created for the ProductService
If you want to learn more about scope look here 
Also I recommend you to read the container API for more understanding about how it work
